# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/native-audio

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

i'm trying to install [Native Audio](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/)
but i receive this error:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@3.4.2
@ionic-native/native-audio@3.6.1
```

I've deleted the 'node_modules' folder and npm install the dependencies but I still receive this error.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.1.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.6",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: it's not an error, rather a warning that  @ionic-native/core expects @ionic-native/native-audio@3.6.1 to be installed. so just install it.

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file?

Comment: I've edit my question with the package.json file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I duplicated your dependencies and the warning is regarding the specified version of @ionic-native/core

Your project.json specifies **3.4.2**
but **3.6.0** is required.

If you update your project.json dependencies to the following the warning should go away (dont forget to run `npm cache clean` before `npm install`)

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
"@angular/core": "4.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
"@angular/http": "4.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.6.0",
"@ionic-native/native-audio": "^3.6.1",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"ionic-angular": "3.1.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.1.1",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.5"
}
```

Comment: Updated answer with specific version.

Comment: Works Great! Thanks!